# Push item to array, only first property is included. Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Schema:

```
let projectSchema = new Schema({
  filters: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true},
      items: {
        q: { type: Number, required: true}
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

Update function:

```
const project = await mongoose.model('project').findById(id).exec();
    console.log(filter); // { name: 'abc', items: [ { q: 3}]
    project.filters.push(filter);
    console.log(project.filters); // { _id: "123", name: 'abc' } // items array is missing
    await project.save();
```

When I fetch a document via mongoose, then add an item to an array of that doc, only the first property is included.

Why is that?

I prefer not to use $push since the benefits of mongoose (validation etc) is not respected when $push is used.

Comment: Show us the schema and the document

Comment: @TechWisdom I've updated the question with schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items field is an object instead of an array. Change your schema:

```
let projectSchema = new Schema({
  filters: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true},
      items: [ // square brackets here
        q: { type: Number, required: true}
      ]
    }
  ],
})
```

Comment: @Joe Glad to assist!